# DRBD comes up after reboot with Connected Diskless/Diskless

Tags: debian, devices, block-device, proxmox, drbd

After an unattented power loss, facing a major issue, every reboot the **DBRB** comes up with **Connected Diskless/Diskless** status.

**main problems:**

> - dump-md response: Found meta data is "unclean"
> - apply-al command terminated with exit code 20 with message open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
> - drbd resource config cannot be opened exclusive.

**About the environment:**

This drbd resource normaly used as a block storage for lvm, which configured as an (shared lvm) storage to a proxmox ve 5.3-8 cluster. On top of drbd block device an lvm configured. As it recommended on drbd host lvm config the device (/dev/nvme0n1p1) below drbd serivice are filtered out (/etc/lvm/lvm.conf shown below)

*The device under drbd is an PCIe NVMe device*

It has some extra properties shown by systemctl:

```
root@pmx0:~# systemctl list-units | grep nvme
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-0000:0c:00.0-nvme-nvme0-nvme0n1-nvme0n1p1.device             loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:0c:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-0000:0c:00.0-nvme-nvme0-nvme0n1.device                       loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:0c:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1
```

Other storage device normal SAS disks listing in sytemctl looks a little different:

```
root@pmx0:~# systemctl list-units | grep sdb
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:0b:00.0-host0-target0:2:1-0:2:1:0-block-sdb-sdb1.device loaded active     plugged   PERC_H710 1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:0b:00.0-host0-target0:2:1-0:2:1:0-block-sdb-sdb2.device loaded active     plugged   PERC_H710 2
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:0b:00.0-host0-target0:2:1-0:2:1:0-block-sdb.device      loaded active     plugged   PERC_H710
```

list NVMe /sys/devices/.. with ls:

```
root@pmx0:~# ls /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:0c:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p1
alignment_offset  dev  discard_alignment  holders  inflight  partition  power  ro  size  start  stat  subsystem  trace  uevent
```

**Things are NOT hepls:**

- Reboot again not help
- drbd service restart not help
- drbdadm detach/disconnect/attach/service restart not help
- nfs-kernel-server service aren't confiured on these drbd nodes (so cannot unconfigure nfs-server)

**After some investigation:**

> dump-md response: Found **meta data is "unclean"**, please apply-al first
>   apply-al command terminated with exit code 20 with this message:
>   open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) **failed: Device or resource busy**
>
> It seems that the **problem is that this device** (/dev/nvme0n1p1) used by my
>   drbd resource config **cannot be opened exclusive**.

**Failing DRBD commands:**

```
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm attach r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm apply-al r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20

root@pmx0:~# drbdadm dump-md r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy

Exclusive open failed. Do it anyways?
[need to type 'yes' to confirm] yes

Found meta data is "unclean", please apply-al first
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal dump-md' terminated with exit code 255
```

**DRBD service status/commands:**

```
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Secondary Diskless/Diskless
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm dstate r0
Diskless/Diskless
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm disconnect r0
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  . . .
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm detach r0
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  . . .
```

**Trying reattach resource r0:**

```
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm attach r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm apply-al r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
```

**lsof, fuser zero output:**

```
root@pmx0:~# lsof /dev/nvme0n1p1
root@pmx0:~# fuser /dev/nvme0n1p1
root@pmx0:~# fuser /dev/nvme0n1
root@pmx0:~# lsof /dev/nvme0n1
```

**Resource disk partition and LVM config:**

```
root@pmx0:~# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.9 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x59762e31

Device         Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048 3825207295 3825205248  1.8T 83 Linux
root@pmx0:~# pvs
  PV             VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb2      pve          lvm2 a--  135.62g  16.00g
root@pmx0:~# vgs
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  pve            1   3   0 wz--n- 135.62g  16.00g
root@pmx0:~# lvs
  LV            VG           Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data          pve          twi-a-tz--  75.87g             0.00   0.04
  root          pve          -wi-ao----  33.75g
  swap          pve          -wi-ao----   8.00g
root@pmx0:~# vi /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
root@pmx0:~# cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep nvm
        filter = [ "r|/dev/nvme0n1p1|", "a|/dev/sdb|", "a|sd.*|", "a|drbd.*|", "r|.*|" ]
```

**DRBD resource config:**

```
root@pmx0:~# cat /etc/drbd.d/r0.res
resource r0 {
        protocol C;
        startup {
                wfc-timeout  0;     # non-zero wfc-timeout can be dangerous (http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/3465-Is-it-safe-to-use-wfc-timeout-in-DRBD-configuration)
                degr-wfc-timeout 300;
        become-primary-on both;
        }
        net {
                cram-hmac-alg sha1;
                shared-secret "*********";
                allow-two-primaries;
                after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
                after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
                after-sb-2pri disconnect;
                #data-integrity-alg crc32c;     # has to be enabled only for test and disabled for production use (check man drbd.conf, section "NOTES ON DATA INTEGRITY")
        }
        on pmx0 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/nvme0n1p1;
                address 10.0.20.15:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on pmx1 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/nvme0n1p1;
                address 10.0.20.16:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        disk {
                # no-disk-barrier and no-disk-flushes should be applied only to systems with non-volatile (battery backed) controller caches.
                # Follow links for more information:
                # http://www.drbd.org/users-guide-8.3/s-throughput-tuning.html#s-tune-disable-barriers
                # http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-throughput-tuning.html#s-tune-disable-barriers
                no-disk-barrier;
                no-disk-flushes;
        }
}
```

**OTHER NODE:**

```
root@pmx1:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Secondary Diskless/Diskless
```

and so on every command responses and configurations showing the same like node pmx0 above...

**Debian and DRBD versions:**

```
root@pmx0:~# uname -a
Linux pmx0 4.15.18-10-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-32 (Sat, 19 Jan 2019 10:09:37 +0100) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@pmx0:~# cat /etc/debian_version
9.8
root@pmx0:~# dpkg --list| grep drbd
ii  drbd-utils                           8.9.10-2                       amd64        RAID 1 over TCP/IP for Linux (user utilities)
root@pmx0:~# lsmod | grep drbd
drbd                  364544  1
lru_cache              16384  1 drbd
libcrc32c              16384  2 dm_persistent_data,drbd
root@pmx0:~# modinfo drbd
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.18-10-pve/kernel/drivers/block/drbd/drbd.ko
alias:          block-major-147-*
license:        GPL
version:        8.4.10
description:    drbd - Distributed Replicated Block Device v8.4.10
author:         Philipp Reisner <phil@linbit.com>, Lars Ellenberg <lars@linbit.com>
srcversion:     9A7FB947BDAB6A2C83BA0D4
depends:        lru_cache,libcrc32c
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           drbd
vermagic:       4.15.18-10-pve SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           allow_oos:DONT USE! (bool)
parm:           disable_sendpage:bool
parm:           proc_details:int
parm:           minor_count:Approximate number of drbd devices (1-255) (uint)
parm:           usermode_helper:string
```

**MOUNTS:**

```
root@pmx0:~# cat /proc/mounts
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=24679656k,nr_inodes=6169914,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=4940140k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mapper/pve-root / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=39,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=20879 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
sunrpc /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/intelSSD700G ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs fuse.lxcfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /etc/pve fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
10.0.0.15:/samba/shp /mnt/pve/bckNFS nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.0.15,mountvers=3,mountport=42772,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.15 0 0
```

Comment: I am not going to post this below as an answer as I am not 100% certain this is your issue. Still, I seem to recall having a similar issue that required also disabling cache (write_cache_state = 0) and disabling lvmetad (use_lvmetad = 0) in the lvm.conf. You also want to stop and disable the lvm2-lvmetad service and lvm2-lvmetad.socket. It is also considered a good practice to update the initrd after changing the lvm.conf.

Comment: @Dok: tried out, but still the device busy

/etc/lvm/lvm.conf:

use_lvmetad = 0

write_cache_state = 0

Comment: I found something new what could be inmportant
The device under drbd is an PCIe NVMe device and it has some extra properties shown by systemctl compared to normal SATA or SAS devices.

The systemctl command outpust explained in the original question under the **About the environment** title

Comment: You've filtered out /dev/nvme0n1p1 in your lvm config. Could you filter out /dev/nvme0n1 as well?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue in my setup, however i found in `drbd` configuration we are giving LVM name in the configuration which means when we will bring up the `drbd` service it will mount the mount point itself as per the configuration.

I found the mount point was defined in `/etc/fstab` which suppose to be commented and should not be mounted by the OS.

Thats how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best would be removing `a|sd.*|` and `r|/dev/nvme0n1p1|` and leaving only what's actually needed. The O/S is installed on `/dev/sdb` (which is being used by LVM) , so in theory the only thing you need to add (include into lvm scanning), is just `/dev/sdb` and `drbd.*` and exclude anything else. So, the filter section should look like the below...

```
filter = [ "a|/dev/sdb|", "a|drbd.*|", "r|.*|" ]
```

In addition to the above, check if there are multiple occurences of the `filter =` entry in the `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` file. If multiple entries are present, then they can produce conflicts.